# Python3 character maps to <undefined> (MINGW64, Windows 10)?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, mingw

I try to use this code, that I found on https://superuser.com/questions/876572/how-do-i-find-out-which-font-contains-a-certain-special-character/1452828, on MINGW64 Python3 on a Windows 10 machine:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import unicodedata
import os
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont

fonts = []

for root,dirs,files in os.walk("c:/Windows/Fonts/"):
  for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".ttf"):
      tfile = os.path.join(root,file)
      fonts.append(tfile)

def char_in_font(unicode_char, font):
  for cmap in font['cmap'].tables:
    if cmap.isUnicode():
      if ord(unicode_char) in cmap.cmap:
        return True
  return False

def test(char):
  for fontpath in fonts:
    font = TTFont(fontpath)   # specify the path to the font in question
    if char_in_font(char, font):
      #print(char + " "+ unicodedata.name(char) + " in " + fontpath) # UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f63a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
      #print( "{} ({}) in {}".format(char, unicodedata.name(char), fontpath ) ) # UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f63a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
      print( "({}) in {}".format( unicodedata.name(char), fontpath ) )

test(u"")
test(u"")
```

If you run the code as-is, you'll see that it works, since it outputs stuff like:

```
$ python3 /tmp/test-font.py
(SMILING CAT FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH) in c:/Windows/Fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
(SMILING CAT FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH) in c:/Windows/Fonts/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
(SMILING CAT FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH) in c:/Windows/Fonts/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
...
```

... however, if you uncomment one on the commented prints, then the code will fail with:

```
$ python3 /tmp/test-font.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/msys64/tmp/test-font.py", line 31, in <module>
    test(u"\U0001f63a")
  File "C:/msys64/tmp/test-font.py", line 29, in test
    print( "{} ({}) in {}".format(char, unicodedata.name(char), fontpath ) )
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/encodings/cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f63a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

This is completely bizarre to me, since `char` is the input variable - it is apparently correctly found in system fonts - and yet, it fails to print in terminal ?!?!

Does anyone have an idea how can I get `char` to print in terminal in this case?

Comment: Your console is not UTF-8 compatible. Python try to convert strings to console encoding, and it find that some characters are not supported by your console). `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` should solve this, in mingw.

Comment: Would your script work if run from pure `cmd` (without _mingw_)? I mean something like `python \tmp\test-font.py` works for me with environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`…

Comment: Thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi and @ JosefZ - `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python3 /tmp/test-font.py` still raises error, `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python3 /tmp/test-font.py` does not raise error, but prints `??` for character, and from straight `cmd.exe`, running `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python3.exe C:\msys64\tmp\test-font.py` also does not raise error, but prints `??` for character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MingGW's console is converting the string to the console encoding (`cp1252` from the error message`) and that encoding doesn't support the full range of Unicode characters.

The standard Windows console does not get the error.  Below is a cut-and-paste from the `cmd.exe` Windows console.

```
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\U0001f63a')
```

Here's a screenshot of the actual display.  The character isn't supported by the font and the console displays the replacement character glyph, but the character is correct as evidenced by the cut-and-paste of the same text above.  There are two because the character requires two UTF-16 code units for its encoding:

[image: windows console display]